# How to get Time column as Pivot table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a report based on Monthly Cycle time in Pivot Format.
I tried to do the same using below Query by converting Time to Integer. But in the report i couldnt able to show it in Time format.
I converted Time datatype to Integer because, Pivot Table only allows aggregated values. Average_Cycle_Time is in "Time" Datatype and Average_Cycle_Time_I  is in "Integer".

Sample Data:
Station  Month    Average_Cycle_Time
AA       April      12:22:00
AA       May        22:16:00
BB       April      16:06:00
BB       May        05:30:00

Expected Result:
Station       April         May
AA            12:22:00      22:16:00
BB            16:06:00      05:30:00

Whereas, I am getting the result as:
Station       April        May
AA            122200       221600
BB            160600       53000

here is the Query i used to get the table in Pivot Format:

```
with t1 as(
select station,avg([Average_Cycle_Time_I]) Avg_cycle_tm from [dbo].[V_FM_Cycle_Time] group by station )
,
t2 as(
SELECT distinct *
FROM (SELECT [Station],[Rake_Type_Name],Datename(Month,[Month]) as [Month name],
[Average_Cycle_Time_I]

FROM [dbo].[V_FM_Cycle_Time]

GROUP BY [Station],[Rake_Type_Name],Datename(Month,[Month]),
[Average_Cycle_Time_I]) AS MonthlyData
PIVOT(avg([Average_Cycle_Time_I])
    FOR [Month Name] IN ([April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December],[January],[February],[March]
 )) AS MonthPivot)
 select t2.*,t1.Avg_cycle_tm from t1, t2 where t1.Station=t2.Station
```

Help Needed.
Thanks in advance 
chandana

Comment: Show sample input expected output data. _You **know** want you want. So don't expect us to guess._

Comment: What is the type of `Avg_Cycle_Time` and why do you cast it to datetime then float then datetime again (?) then convert to string? Just try [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql#ExampleD)

Comment: `avg([Average_Cycle_Time_I])` doesn't make sense either for `varchar` or `time`. `time` is the *time of day*, not a duration. You can't average either text or time of day. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked that you said you were using the [TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) type, and used [AVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql) on it without errors. Actually that doesn't works, should return error:

> Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator

---

If that is an integer, and you want to display it as a "Time", you could try that:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, Avg_Cycle_Time, ''), 114)
```

Must return something like:

> 00:02:33

*The magic number 114 means hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h). [See more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)*

Comment: Formatting values as strings is best done with FORMAT